# Create a public AMI of EC2 in AWS without access to sensitive data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm interested in creating a copy of an EC2 and share it with another user from another account, after researching a bit i noticed that creating an AMI (Amazon Machine Image) is the easiest path for this.

however many of these images have sensitive info on them which im not interested to expose or share, im only interested that the use will be able to reproduce the exact copy of the machine so he can test various configuration changes and see their effects

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't have both an exact copy and a copy minus certain data. Presume you want the latter. Why not create a temporary AMI from the EC2 instance, then launch an EC2 instance from that AMI, then log into the instance, remove the data that you want removed (basically reset it to the state you want), and then capture a new AMI from that.

Comment: Im looking for a solution that is easy for the user and doesnt involves many steps

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You, the person creating, resetting, re-creating, and sharing the AMI, are the one doing this work. If that process is too complex then you can’t do it this way, so go back to a stock AMI and build from there.

Comment: The user is a third party. I will do scanning on the ami but i need the third person (who might not be very technical) to be able to create easly and feel safetly sharing this ami with a person who he doesnt know

Comment: This is a very ambiguous requirement. Only the third party will know what they consider sensitive data. You could wipe their user profiles (and attendant files) but would that suffice? You should probably start from a base AWS AMI and supply automation to bring it up to the level you need.

Comment: exacly most people start with base ami and than install some packages on it (java, tomcat, apache) i would like to obtain that exact configuration but without the user data (which i suppose no sane user in the world would anyway want to expose to me)